# Is it worth to take another sample?

Tags: self-study, estimation, sampling

There is a random normal variable, with unknown mean and std. I want to estimate the mean by sampling. After several samples, I have an estimate, which I can make more precise by taking more samples, however each additional sample has a cost.

How can I estimate, from the samples I currently have, the effect on an additional sample on the accuracy of my estimate of the mean?

Comment: I've tagged this as homework because it sounds a lot like a homework question, let me know if I'm wrong.  Click on the homework tag for some info on our policy on homework.

Comment: Perhaps the question you are given uses the word "accuracy" but I think ["precision"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) is more to the point.  Let's start with a slightly simpler question than the one you ask.  What statistic describes the precision of an estimate of the population mean?  Say your initial sample of n=5 comes back: (3, 5, 5, 7, 8).   Can you calculate the statistic I just asked for with this sample?

Comment: A. This is not a homework question, although the motivation does come from a homework assignment... It's an assignment in AI, developing a multi-agent cooperative system, where one of the decisions each agent has to make is, whether or not to broadcast its observations to its peers. I currently try to approach this by calculating the value of each additional observation, and comparing it to the cost of broadcast. There may be better approaches to the multi-agent problem, however, I think this is an interesting question by itself.

Comment: B. Do you mean the standard error / confidence interval? Well, for {3,5,5,7,8} the estimated mean is 5.6, the calculated standard deviation is 1.744, and the standard error is 1.744/sqrt(5) = 0.78. So, a condifence interval of 95% will be: 5.6 +- 1.53

Comment: Also, I think I do need the accuracy (not the precision) - I want the estimation to be as close as possible to the true value.

Comment: I think you're right that it isn't enough just to consider precision/variance.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, the standard error of the mean (aka standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the mean) describes your uncertainty about the population mean.  So I think its fair to reduce your question to, how does the standard error of the mean change with increasing sample size?  As the formula for the S.E. (S.D./sqrt(n)) implies, halving the standard error would typically require quadrupling the sample size.  Reducing the SE by 90% requires increasing the sample 100 times.

If your sample is a non-trivial fraction of the entire population then the simple formula for the SE of the population is not quite right.  There may be other exceptions, which I hope other people will point out, but I hope this gives you a rough idea of how to proceed.

Comment: This assumes that the S.D. will remain constant. However, I do not know the true std, all I have is the sample std, and an additional sample may also change that.

Comment: Haha, yeah, to be honest, that crossed my mind as I was responding and then I thought, "I don't know how to deal with that - I'll just post what I have." It should be a fairly trivial consideration if your sample is already n>=30 but I'm not sure what to do about very small samples. Hopefully someone else can chime in here.